# On an Android phone, how to create a shortcut to read new Gmail emails with a specific tag?

Tags: email, gmail, home-screen-shortcuts

On my Android phone, to be specific a Google Pixel 2 XL, where I use Gmail app to receive and read emails, I'd like to have a shortcut to read new emails tagged with a specific tag. How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

1. On your home screen, long-press an empty space, then select widgets.
2. Look for "Gmail label". Add it to your screen. You might be prompted to select an account if you have multiple one.
3. Select the label, give it a name and click "Done".
4. A shortcut to emails with a particular label will be created on your home screen.